# Domain Swapping

Tags: linux, domain

If I have two servers, each with their own domain name and I wish to swap those domains so the opposing server recieves it, all I have to change is the @ A records to the other IP, right?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, changing both A records should be sufficient as long as you haven't also defined the MX records by IP instead of hostname.  CNAME records are aliased to the A record hostname, so they will automatically follow to the new IP when the A record changes.

If you have Apache virtualhost configs that reference the old hostnames, you will need to change those, of course.

Comment: Okay great, what exactly does the A record do and why do the other records stay the same?

Comment: @mcfan42 The A record maps a hostname directly to an IP.  If you have CNAME records, those alias other hostnames to the A record so as long as the A record resolves correctly they will as well.  If you have defined an MX record by IP address rather than hostname, you would need to change that too.

Comment: So basically, all other records will stay the same... only the @ A record needs to be changed to do what I'm trying to achieve?

Comment: @mcfan42 It should be enough.  It will take a few hours before DNS caches around the world expire and they reach the new IP

Comment: sounds good...  no need to worry about backing up my servers, right? No concern for losing data?

Comment: @mcfan42 you should have backups anyway, but the DNS change doesn't touch your server so it shouldn't be an issue.